# Loop executing 3 times

Tags: java

I am working on a school exercise that asks me to modify the `.java` code so that the user is asked to input the right number **only** 3 times.

The code I get is this:

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valorUsuari = 0;
        boolean valorNOk=true;
        while (valorNOk){
            System.out.print("Insert a number between 0 and 5: ");
            valorUsuari = lector.nextInt();
            lector.nextLine();
            if((valorUsuari >= 0)&&(valorUsuari <= 5)){
              valorNOk=false;    
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Data correct. You typed " + valorUsuari);
    }
}
```

I tried doing this before the while condition and it doesn't seem to work:

```
for (valorUsuari = 0; valorUsuari <= 3 ; valorUsuari++)
```

Do you have any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is not working? Is it printing 4 times? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Oh, do you mean he has only 3 tries? After that he is not allowed to enter anymore?

Comment: Hi. I get no error but it doesn't stop after third insert.

Comment: Third successful insert, or third try?

Comment: Yes, it suppose to give just 3 tries to enter the right number and then give an error.

Comment: Works like a charm! So the idea is to add a int that is used to count the times. I was trying to count the keyboard input (silly me). If I were to show an error message cause it triggered the 3 time try, where should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a counter that starts at 0 and when it hits 3, the user is no longer allowed to enter a number. Every time the users writes something illegal, add one to the counter.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    int valorUsuari = 0;
    int counter = 0; //this is your counter, it starts at 0 because the user has failed 0 times at this point
    boolean valorNOk=true;
    while (valorNOk && counter < 3){
        System.out.print("Insert a number between 0 and 5: ");
        valorUsuari = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        if((valorUsuari >= 0)&&(valorUsuari <= 5)){
          valorNOk=false;    
        } else {
            counter++; //this is added to keep track of failed tries
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Data correct. You typed " + valorUsuari);
}
```

**Note:** This isn't really relevant for you at this point, but your `valorNOk` is pretty redundant. You can simply use `break` instead like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    int valorUsuari = 0;
    int counter = 0; //this is your counter, it starts at 0 because the user has failed 0 times at this point
    while (counter < 3){
        System.out.print("Insert a number between 0 and 5: ");
        valorUsuari = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
        if((valorUsuari >= 0)&&(valorUsuari <= 5)){
            break; 
        } else {
            counter++; //this is added to keep track of failed tries
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Data correct. You typed " + valorUsuari);
}
```

**Another note:** Even if the user inputs wrongly three times, you will still print `"Data correct..."`. What you could do is something like this after your while-loop:

```
if(counter < 3) {
    System.out.println("Data correct. You typed " + valorUsari);
} else {
    System.out.println("Too many tries. You are bad.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying guys but I may not use break nor exit to terminate.

Comment: @ALxALx In that case, your boolean is fine.

Comment: You simply knocked it! Thank you for the advance in terminating the program!

Answer (score 0):

Modified it a bit, I used a counter `int tries` to keep track of the tries.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valorUsuari = 0;
        boolean valorNOk = true;
        int tries = 0;
        while (valorNOk && tries < 3) {
            System.out.print("Insert a number between 0 and 5: ");
            valorUsuari = lector.nextInt();
            lector.nextLine();
           if ((valorUsuari >= 0) && (valorUsuari <= 5)) {
            valorNOk = false;
        } else {
            tries++;
        }
        System.out.println("Data correct. You typed " + valorUsuari);
    }
```

Comment: At first I was thinking at a break inside the code but they ask me not to use break nor exit().